# Sinatra Activerecord: private method `load' called for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, sinatra, version

I have a **Sinatra** app that uses **Activerecord** gem. Everything used to run well until some moment my code just stopped working. The only thing that I did in between is update my Gemfile with `bundle update`.

Now this code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'

set :database_file, "../../config/database.yml"
```

raises **/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:32:in database_file=: private method 'load' called for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)**.

I tried to rollback to previous *Gemfile.lock* version, but error persisits.
What should be my next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting

`set :database, {adapter: 'postgresql', database: '_your_database_name_'`}

instead of

`set :database_file, "../../config/database.yml"`

helps, but I'm still not sure where the bug came from.